# integral of square of real part of analytic function over a circle

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis

I am looking at bounding some terms. I was wondering if anyone knew of any upper bounds for integrals of the following form: Let f be an analytic function on $\{z: |z| >1\}$ Let $\epsilon\in(0,1/2)$, $c\in(0,1]$ be given and $e^{\sigma}\geq 1+c^{1/2-\epsilon}$. For all $|z|\geq 1+c^{1/2-\epsilon}$
$$
\int_0^{2\pi} \dfrac{(\Re f(e^{\sigma+i\theta}))^2}{e^{-i\theta}z -1} d\theta.
$$

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: You need to tell us much more. Where is $f$ analytic, where is $z,$ etc

Comment: I'm sorry that it is not a well formed question. I really just wanted to know if anyone could direct me to any results of similar type. I do not know exactly what I am needing to bound yet but am seeing similar things to what I have tried to write.